# Simplify Array Query with Range

Tags: sql, arrays, database, google-bigquery

i have a big query datatable with 512 variables as arrays with quite the long names (x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_0__arrValues to arrSlices_511). In each array are 360 values. the bi-tool cannot compute an array in this form. this is the reason why i want to have each value as an output.

the query excerpt i use right now is:

```
SELECT
 timestamp, x_stArrayTag_sArrayName, x_stArrayTag_sComission,
 1 as row,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(1)] AS f001,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(10)] AS f010,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(20)] AS f020,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(30)] AS f030,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(40)] AS f040,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(50)] AS f050,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(60)] AS f060,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(70)] AS f070,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(80)] AS f080,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(90)] AS f090,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(100)] AS f100,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(110)] AS f110,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(120)] AS f120,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(130)] AS f130,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(140)] AS f140,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(150)] AS f150,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(160)] AS f160,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(170)] AS f170,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(180)] AS f180,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(190)] AS f190,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(200)] AS f200,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(210)] AS f210,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(220)] AS f220,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(230)] AS f230,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(240)] AS f240,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(250)] AS f250,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(260)] AS f260,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(270)] AS f270,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(280)] AS f280,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(290)] as f290,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(300)] AS f300,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(310)] AS f310,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(320)] AS f320,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(330)] AS f330,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(340)] AS f340,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(350)] AS f350,
 x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1__arrValues[OFFSET(359)] AS f359

 FROM
 `project.table` 

 WHERE
 _PARTITIONTIME >= "2017-01-01 00:00:00"
 AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-02-16 00:00:00"

UNION ALL
```

The output i get is unfortunately only a fracture of all values. getting all 512*360 values with this query is not possible because if i used this query for all slices i reach the limit of bigquery.

is there a possibility to rename the the long name and to select a range?

best regards
scotti

Comment: While it's possible to change your query to fit into the 256KB query length limit, you will end up having ~180000 columns which exceeds BigQuery limit of 10000 columns. Is this really the output you need, or would you prefer to have 360 rows and 512 columns?

Comment: ~180000 columns are quite many. 
i need the most suitable output for analytics. 360 rows and 512 columns should do just fine.

Comment: depends on what really you do then with your data  - it can be either 360 rows and 512 columns OR 512 rows and 360 columns (the later somehow sounds more suitable for what I am hearing so far) - but still - can you share what kind of magic you do then with whatever BI tool you use. It might be possible that all that magic can be done within BigQuery so there will be no need for restructuring your table at all - just wild guess :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can get 360 rows and 512 columns by using UNNEST. Here is a small example:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    [1, 2, 3, 4] as a,
    [2, 3, 4, 5] as b,
    [3, 4, 5, 6] as c
)
SELECT v1, b[OFFSET(off)] as v2, c[OFFSET(off)] as v3
FROM data, unnest(a) as v1 WITH OFFSET off
```

Output:

```
v1  v2  v3   
1   2   3    
2   3   4    
3   4   5    
4   5   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind a little messy table you are dealing with - in making decision on restructuring the important aspect is practicality of query to implement that decision

In your specific case  - I would recommend full flattening of the data like below (each row will be transformed into ~180000 rows each representing one of the elements of one of the array in original row - slice field will represent array number and pos will represent element position in that array) - query is generic enough to handle any number/names of slices and array sizes and at the same time result is flexible and also generic enough to be used in any imaginable algorithm

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  slice,
  pos,
  value
FROM `project.dataset.messytable` t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_(\d+)":\[.*?\]')) slice WITH OFFSET x
JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_\d+":\[(.*?)\]')) arr WITH OFFSET y
ON x = y,
UNNEST(SPLIT(arr)) value WITH OFFSET pos
```

you can test/play with it using below dummy example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.messytable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 
    [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_0, 
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1,
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, 
    [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_0, 
    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_1,
    [26, 27, 28, 29, 30] x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_2 
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  slice,
  pos,
  value
FROM `project.dataset.messytable` t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_(\d+)":\[.*?\]')) slice WITH OFFSET x
JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"x__x_arrVal_arrSlices_\d+":\[(.*?)\]')) arr WITH OFFSET y
ON x = y,
UNNEST(SPLIT(arr)) value WITH OFFSET pos
```

the result is as below

```
Row id  slice   pos value    
1   1   0       0     1  
2   1   0       1     2  
3   1   0       2     3  
4   1   0       3     4  
5   1   0       4     5  
6   1   1       0     11     
7   1   1       1     12     
8   1   1       2     13     
9   1   1       3     14     
10  1   1       4     15     
11  1   2       0     21     
12  1   2       1     22     
13  1   2       2     23     
14  1   2       3     24     
15  1   2       4     25     
16  2   0       0     6  
17  2   0       1     7  
18  2   0       2     8  
19  2   0       3     9  
20  2   0       4     10     
21  2   1       0     16     
22  2   1       1     17     
23  2   1       2     18     
24  2   1       3     19     
25  2   1       4     20     
26  2   2       0     26     
27  2   2       1     27     
28  2   2       2     28     
29  2   2       3     29     
30  2   2       4     30
```